# problem with distribution of subfigures

Tags: beamer, floats, margins, subfloats

I've been trying to arrange my figures in my beamer presentation as the attached example without success, could anyone please give me an example to do so? I like the way it is arranged and the margin spacing, thanks in advance for any hints,[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can organize them with `columns` environment help.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Organizing figures}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\column[T]{.7\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\column[T]{.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}\\
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\end{columns}
Some caption
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that looks nice and promising, I'll give it a shot, thanks for that, let you know if it works. I tried subfloat, subfigure and subfig without success. I read about tabular also but looks that it's more complicated, though.